# How to configure static serving in twisted with django

Tags: django, static, twisted

I have a django application running under twisted with the following service:

```
class JungoHttpService(internet.TCPServer):

    def __init__(self, port):
        self.__port = port
        pool = threadpool.ThreadPool()
        wsgi_resource = TwoStepResource(reactor, pool, WSGIHandler())
        internet.TCPServer.__init__(self, port, Site(wsgi_resource))
        self.setName("WSGI/HttpJungo")
        self.pool = pool

    def startService(self):
        internet.TCPServer.startService(self)
        self.pool.start()

    def stopService(self):
        self.pool.stop()
        return internet.TCPServer.stopService(self)

    def getServerPort(self):
        """ returns the port number the server is listening on"""
        return self.__port
```

Here is my TwoStepResource:

```
class TwoStepResource(WSGIResource):

    def render (self, request):
        if request.postpath:
            pathInfo = '/' + '/'.join(request.postpath)
        else:
            pathInfo = ''
        try:
            callback, callback_args, 
            callback_kwargs = urlresolvers.resolve(pathInfo)

            if hasattr(callback, "async"):
                # Patch the request
                _patch_request(request, callback, callback_args, 
                               callback_kwargs)
        except Exception, e:
            logging.getLogger('jungo.request').error("%s : %s\n%s" % (
                      e.__class__.__name__, e, traceback.format_exc()))

            raise
        finally:
            return super(TwoStepResource, self).render(request)
```

How can I add serving media files ("/media") to the same port?

Comment: It's hard to understand incomplete code examples.  What is a `TwoStepResource`?  It's not any class that Twisted Web itself provides.

Comment: Added the TwoStepResource to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `wsgi_resource.putChild('media', File("/path/to/media"))` after the `wsgi_resource` assignment. You'll need to `from twisted.web.static import File` of course.

Update 1:

Turns out [`WSGIResource`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.web.wsgi.WSGIResource.html) rejects putChild() attempts. There's a solution here: http://blog.vrplumber.com/index.php?/archives/2426-Making-your-Twisted-resources-a-url-sub-tree-of-your-WSGI-resource....html

Update 2:

**jungo.py**

```
from twisted.application import internet
from twisted.web import resource, wsgi, static, server
from twisted.python import threadpool
from twisted.internet import reactor

def wsgiApplication(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['Hello, world!']

class SharedRoot(resource.Resource):
    """Root resource that combines the two sites/entry points"""
    WSGI = None

    def getChild(self, child, request):
        request.prepath.pop()
        request.postpath.insert(0, child)
        return self.WSGI

    def render(self, request):
        return self.WSGI.render(request)

class JungoHttpService(internet.TCPServer):

    def __init__(self, port):
        self.__port = port
        pool = threadpool.ThreadPool()
        sharedRoot = SharedRoot()

                          # substitute with your custom WSGIResource
        sharedRoot.WSGI = wsgi.WSGIResource(reactor, pool, wsgiApplication)
        sharedRoot.putChild('media', static.File("/path/to/media"))
        internet.TCPServer.__init__(self, port, server.Site(sharedRoot))
        self.setName("WSGI/HttpJungo")
        self.pool = pool

    def startService(self):
        internet.TCPServer.startService(self)
        self.pool.start()

    def stopService(self):
        self.pool.stop()
        return internet.TCPServer.stopService(self)

    def getServerPort(self):
        """ returns the port number the server is listening on"""
        return self.__port
```

**jungo.tac**

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from jungo import JungoHttpService

application = service.Application("jungo")
jungoService = JungoHttpService(8080)
jungoService.setServiceParent(application)
```

`$ twistd -n -y jungo.tac`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After doing that, I get the following error: "Cannot put IResource children under WSGIResource"

Comment: Oops, thought I could get away with it, I've never actually used WSGIResource - assumed it was just like any other IResource. Updated my answer with a link to a solution.

Comment: Thanks. But where do I insert it in my code? Tried to add it to my TwoStepResource, but got:

Comment: "Cannot put IResource children under WSGIResource"

Comment: You don't need to change TwoStepResource. You need create a placeholder root resource that passes the unaltered request paths directly to the WSGI resource - effectively elevating the WSGI resource to root status. I've added a working example to my answer. For brevity I'm using a simple WSGIResource instead of your TwoStepResource.

Comment: Ok. Now I get: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isLeaf'

Comment: Twisted-10.2.0/twisted/web/resource.py, line 58 in getChildForRequest

Comment: I believe that I've answered the original question - now we're dealing with something else it's probably best that we discuss it out-of-band. Email me the full traceback and your code, I'll try to have a look. p/e\t/e\r/@\h/y\p/e\r/p\l/e\x/.\n/e\t

Comment: Can you explain how this can be ran without `twistd` (i.e. as a regular Python application)?